# Error in memset() a 3D array

Tags: c, memset

I dynamically allocate a 3D array:

```
int n1=2,n2=5,n3=3;
int in1,in2,in3;
float ***a;
a = (float ***)malloc(n1*sizeof(float **));
for (in1=0;in1<n1;in1++)
    a[in1] = (float **)malloc(n2*sizeof(float *));
for (in1=0;in1<n1;in1++)
    for (in2=0;in2<n2;in2++)
        a[in1][in2] = (float *)malloc(n3*sizeof(float));
```

After that I want to initialize this 3D array. The conventional way is:

```
for (in1=0; in1<n1; in1++)            
    for (in2=0; in2<n2; in2++)      
        for (in3=0; in3<n3; in3++)  
            a[in1][in2][in3] = 1.0f;
```

However, if I want to use `memset()` to initialize the array, it seems unfeasible because the first input is *ptr. So if I write

```
memset(a[0],1,n1*n2*n3*sizeof(float));
```

The first input a[0] is a **ptr, which is wrong.
If I write:

```
memset(a[0][0],1,n2*n3*sizeof(float));
```

The first input is a *ptr, but there's no n1-dimension any more.

So I'm wondering if `memset()` can only be used to initialize a 2D matrix?

** I understand memset can't be used on 3D array, but for 2D array I think it's feasible. Here's an example:

```
int n1=2,n2=5;
int in1,in2;
float **a;
a = (float **)malloc(n1*sizeof(float *));
for (in1=0;in1<n1;in1++)
    a[in1] = (float *)malloc(n2*sizeof(float));
memset(a[0],0,n1*n2*sizeof(float));
free(*a);free(a);
```

This is also not contiguous memory? But it can get correct result.

Comment: nope, you can't, unless you're allocating one big block and assigning the lines. Just create a contiguous matrix with only 1 malloc, then you can memset. But not with `1`...

Comment: There is no 3D array in your code! A pointer is not an array.

Answer (score 3):

Your "3d array" is not really an array of arrays like `memset` expects it to be. If we draw it out it will look something like this:

```
     +------+------+-----+-----------+
a -> | a[0] | a[1] | ... | a[n1 - 1] |
     +------+------+-----+-----------+
             |
             v
             +---------+---------+-----+--------------+
             | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | ... | a[1][n2 - 1] |
             +---------+---------+-----+--------------+
              |
              v
             +------------+------------+-----+-----------------+
             | a[1][0][0] | a[1][0][1] | ... | a[1][0][n3 - 1] |
             +------------+------------+-----+-----------------+
```

This layout is also called *jagged* arrays. But no matter what it is called, your `memset` call expects the memory you write to to be contiguous, which your "3D array" *isn't*.

In short, you can not use `memset` to initialize your arrays.

---

There *are* ways to make it a contiguous memory area, but then you can't really use nice array indexing anymore, but have to use arithmetic to calculate each and every index.

Comment: `void var_init(float **p, float **pz, float **px, float **vx, float **vz)`
    
`/*< variable initialization >*/`

`{`
    `memset(p[0],0,n1*n2*sizeof(float));`
    
`memset(pz[0],0,n1*n2*sizeof(float));`
    `memset(px[0],0,n1*n2*sizeof(float));`
    `memset(vz[0],0,n1*n2*sizeof(float));`
    `memset(vx[0],0,n1*n2*sizeof(float));`
`}`

The above is from an open source code. Why they can use this way, while I can't?

Answer (score 1):

`memset` can only be used to assign a value to a contiguous block of memory - which your 3D array is not. The way you've created it, you create many separate blocks of memory and crucially the chunks that contain the actual values won't be near each other.

You could create the array in one allocation like this

```
float *big_chunk=malloc(sizeof(float)*n1*n2*n3);
```

and then you could use `memset` with it and you'd reference into it like this

```
big_chunk[x*n1+y*n2+z]=some_value;
```