# Confusion on `memset` of a 2D array and error on `free`

Tags: c, free, memset

I use `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory, use `memset` to initialize the 2D array, and use `free` to free the memory. The code is:

```
int n1=2,n2=5;
int in1;
float **a;
a = (float **)malloc(n1*sizeof(float *));
for (in1=0;in1<n1;in1++)
    a[in1] = (float *)malloc(n2*sizeof(float));
memset(a[0],0,n1*n2*sizeof(float));
free(*a);free(a);
```

First problem when I run the code is: 
    *** Error in `./try1': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000c06030 ***

Second question is: since the prerequisite for using `memset` is having contiguous memory. That's why it doesn't work on 3D array (see [Error in memset() a 3D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703042/error-in-memset-a-3d-array)). But here `a` is a 2D pointer or array, the input of `memset` is `a[0]`. My understanding is:

```
  +---------+---------+-----+--------------+
  | a[0][0] | a[0][1] | ... | a[0][n2 - 1] |
  +---------+---------+-----+--------------+
    ^
    |
 +------+------+-----+-----------+
 | a[0] | a[1] | ... | a[n1 - 1] |
 +------+------+-----+-----------+
           |
           v
         +---------+---------+-----+--------------+
         | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | ... | a[1][n2 - 1] |
         +---------+---------+-----+--------------+
```

The above figure shows the contiguous memory. So `memset(a[0],0,n1*n2*sizeof(float));` can successfully initialize `**a`. Am I right? If it's not contiguous, how can the initialization be successful? (it is from the tested open source code)

Comment: You must loop through the array to `free` its pointer elements just as you did to `malloc` them. Then `free(a);` The array is not contiguous, it is not a true 2D array, and it might as well be a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: If you call `malloc` more than once, it is *not* contiguous memory.

Comment: What you have is not a 2D array, but an array of arrays.  They do not take up one contiguous piece of memory, so you cannot use a singular `memset` call to set the whole thing.  You will have to loop through to `memset` and `free` and the like just as you did to `malloc` the memory.  Alternatively, you can `malloc` it all contiguously with a singular call and use arithmetic to figure out the rows and columns.

Comment: If you use `0` as the data for `memset` then you could use `calloc` instead of `malloc` (although the `free` problem is the same.

Comment: @Weather Vane if free iteratively like this: for (in1=0;in1<n1;in1++)
      free(a[in1]);
  free(a);
The error still exists.

Comment: But have you corrected the `memset` problem mentioned? It will cause havoc, and anything after is useless.

Comment: That's because you `memset` all of the pointers in `a` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

> The above figure shows the contiguous memory.

No it doesn't. It shows two regions of contiguous memory: a[0][0] -> a[0][n2 - 1] and a[1][0]  -> a[1][n2 - 1].

You could try to initialize and erase each of them:

```
int n1 = 2, n2 = 5;
int in1;
float **a;
a = (float **)malloc(n1*sizeof(float *));
for (in1 = 0; in1<n1; in1++)
{ 
    a[in1] = (float *)malloc(n2*sizeof(float));
    memset(a[in1], 0, n2*sizeof(float));
}
for (in1 = 0; in1<n1; in1++)
{
    free(*(a+in1));
}
free(a);
```

Only in the case of a 'real' 2d array, like `float a[2][5];`, your assumption about contiguous memory is correct.